# Know the transformation bewteen Perspective and Orthographic

Tags: image-processing, perspective, orthographic

It's me again, for my problem of Orthographic and Perspective point of view.
I wanted to pass a picture from a perspective view to an orthographic one, but it seems it's impossible without more informations such as z-near, and z-far and more.

So I worked a little and found out that I can get the 2 images (one in perspective, the other on orthographic).

The idea I have is to colorize a B&W (orthographic) picture with a coloured (perspective) picture.

Example :

I have this : 
[image]

I have the picture of the Near clipe plane in the 2 cases (O and P). But the Orthographics one is black and white. And I want to colourize the orthographic picture with the perspective one. (In that case, it will be to colourize the darker ball in red, and colourize the lighter ball in yellow... :) )

Do you think it's something possible to do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you gave the previous solution the thumbs up for not giving you a solution - so I dont know where this is going - you need to learn the math !!

Comment: I don't understand the point you're pointing out. I gave the thumb up because he took of his time to tell that there were no solutions to make what I want. If it's true (and this is probably true, due to all responses i got in this way, and the research I made), there's no point trying to solve this problem since it's not one. I think this one isn't the same so I stopped the other and opened this one. But you're right, i'm doing the easiest way, since I don't have much time to do what I want. I will try to understand the process and doing it my way.
Thanks anyway for your response :)